# Mail server (iRedMail) - adding e-mail account to my Gmail over SSL times out

Tags: postfix, dovecot, iredmail

When I try adding my account to Gmail with port 995 it times out. When I checkmark Always use an secured SSL connection in the Gmail add account window I get this error:

> "SSL error: unable to verify the first certificate"

[digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/) gives green checkmarks while testing mail.serv except for

> SSL Certificate is not trusted

I added Acmetool certs to Nginx 00-default.conf as normally.
Added certs to Postfix like so:

```
postconf -e smtpd_tls_cert_file='/var/lib/acme/live/mail.server.com/cert'
postconf -e smtpd_tls_key_file='/var/lib/acme/live/mail.server.com/privkey'
```

Added certs to Dovecot conf like so:

```
ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/mail.server.com/cert;
ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/mail.server.com/privkey;
```

What is this issue about and how do can I try and solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to use was fullchain instead of cert e.g.:

```
acmetool want mail.awesome-server.io

## nginx conf
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/lib/acme/live/mail.awesome-server.io/fullchain;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/lib/acme/live/mail.awesome-server.io/privkey;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

## /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
    ssl_cert = </var/lib/acme/live/mail.awesome-server.io/fullchain
    ssl_key = </var/lib/acme/live/mail.awesome-server.io/privkey

service dovecot restart

postconf -e smtpd_tls_cert_file='/var/lib/acme/live/mail.awesome-server.io/fullchain'
postconf -e smtpd_tls_key_file='/var/lib/acme/live/mail.awesome-server.io/privkey'

service postfix restart
```

Comment: yep, you always need to define intermediate certificate, which is included in the fullchain

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial to setup SSL cert/key in Postfix/Dovecot:
http://www.iredmail.org/docs/use.a.bought.ssl.certificate.html